# where do I set the default node path in drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-path-aliases

I set somewhere, that all new nodes should be published under 'reports' (domain.com/reports/node)
Where can I change this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two possible answers. If you asked exactly what you have asked then you have added a path alias to `node` under `admin/build/path`. Or if instead of `node/1` you see `reports/node/1` then you have pathauto installed and you create a strange pattern `reports/node/[nid]`.

Oh and there is a third one, that you have created a View for *all* nodes. This question requires clarification -- core only has a listing for *promoted* nodes not *all* nodes. Do you have Views installed? Do you have pathauto installed? What happens exactly?

Comment: Thanks, I found it under admin/build/path/patterns!

Answer (score 1):

The existing answer mentions the excellent module [Pathauto](http://drupal.org/project/pathauto) here. From the project description:

> The Pathauto module automatically generates path aliases for various kinds of content (nodes, categories, users) without requiring the user to manually specify the path alias. This allows you to get aliases like /category/my-node-title.html instead of /node/123. The aliases are based upon a "pattern" system which the administrator can control.

Pathauto allows for all kinds of control over Drupal paths for sane URLs and better search visibility. In your case defaults could be set for `/reports` and special cases could be made for other content or content types.